# parsing date with talend open studio throws an error

Tags: java, talend

i need to parse the first date from the following string in a talend open studio job:

`Report fÃ¼r Benutzerdefiniert Von: 11.10.2016 01:00:00 Bis: 12.10.2016 01:00:00`

i build the following expression which is used in tjavarow component to set the date as global var:

```
output_row.Datum = TalendDate.parseDate("dd.MM.yyyy",StringHandling.LEFT(String‌​Handling.FTRIM(Strin‌​gHandling.EREPLACE(i‌​nput_row.Column0,"Re‌​port fÃ¼r Benutzerdefiniert Von: ","")),11));
globalMap.put("datum",output_row.Datum);
```

but i only get this error:

```
Exception in component tJavaRow_2
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11.10.2016"
    at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:895)
    at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:839)
    at ec_bi.xxxx_logintimes_csv_to_db_0_1.xxxx_LoginTImes_CSV_to_DB.tFileInputDelimited_3Process(xxxx_LoginTImes_CSV_to_DB.java:3184)
    at ec_bi.xxxx_logintimes_csv_to_db_0_1.xxxx_LoginTImes_CSV_to_DB.tJavaRow_1_error(xxxx_LoginTImes_CSV_to_DB.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at ec_bi.xxxx_logintimes_csv_to_db_0_1.xxxx_LoginTImes_CSV_to_DB$TalendException.printStackTrace(xxxx_LoginTImes_CSV_to_DB.java:355)
    at ec_bi.xxxx_logintimes_csv_to_db_0_1.xxxx_LoginTImes_CSV_to_DB.runJobInTOS(xxxx_LoginTImes_CSV_to_DB.java:10195)
    at xxx.xxxxxx_csv_to_db_0_1.xxxx_LoginTImes_CSV_to_DB.main(xxxx_xxxxx_CSV_to_DB.java:9946)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11.10.2016"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:881)
    ... 10 more
```

whats wrong with my parse date `TalendDate.parseDate("dd.MM.yyyy",...)`

THANKFULLY

christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was an invisible character.

It's working fine with:

```
output_row.datum = TalendDate.parseDate("dd.MM.yyyy",StringHandling.TRIM(StringHandling.RIGHT(StringHandling.LEFT(StringHandling.EREPLACE(input_row.Column0,"Report fÃ¼r Benutzerdefiniert Von: ",""),11),10)));
```

you can see how i figured out here: https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=193560#p193560

but let me know if there is more glaceful solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis number might be wrong : in the first line there is one ')' too much, 2 more in the second line. 
Besides, in a tJavaRow, the row should be named as "input_row.Column0" and not "row5.Column0".
If you want to use "row5", you should try to put this expression in a tMap

Comment: sorry was a copy/past error - I correct both to

    output_row.Datum = TalendDate.parseDate("dd.MM.yyyy",StringHandling.LEFT(StringHandling.FTRIM(StringHandling.EREPLACE(input_row.Column0,"Report fÃ¼r Benutzerdefiniert Von: ","")),11));
    globalMap.put("datum",output_row.Datum);

but get same error